# Vagrant 2 way folder sync

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I've setup a Vagrant box that runs my webserver to host my Symfony2 application.
Everything works fine except the folder synchronization.

I tried 2 things:

1. config.vm.synced_folder LOCALFOLDER, HOSTFOLDER
2. config.vm.synced_folder LOCALFOLDER, HOSTFOLDER, type="rsync"

**Option 1**: First option works, I actually don't know how file is shared but it works.
Files are copied in both way, but the application is SUPER slow.
Symfony is generating cache files which might be the issue, but I don't really know how to troubleshoot this and see what is happening.

**Option 2:** Sync is only done in one way (from my local machine to the vagrant box), which covers most of the case and is fast.
Issue is that when I use symfony command line on the vagrant box to generate some files they are not copied over to my local machine.

**My question is:**
What is the best way to proceed with 2 ways syncing? With option 1 how can I (as it might be the issue) exclude some files from syncing.
With Option 2 how can I make sure changes on remote are copied to my local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it doesn't seem Vagrant offers a "built-in" way to do this here is what I did:

- Configure Vagrant RSYNC folder on the folders that will contains application generated files (in Symfony2 it is your Bundle/Entity folder). Note that I didn't sync the root folder because  some folders doesn't have to be rsynced (cache/logs...) and also because it was taking way too much time for the rsync process to parse all the folders/subfolders when I know that only the Entity folder will be generated.
  As the Rsync has to be done from the Vagrant box to the host, I use vagrant-rsync-back plugin and thus run this manually everytime I use a command that generates code.
  https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-rsync-back#getting-started
- Create an watcher on my local machine that will track any change in code and rsync it to the vagrant box.
  https://gist.github.com/laurentlemaire/e423b4994c7452cddbd2

Comment: Vagrant has built-in support for NFS and SMB as an alternative for two-way sync. See my answer above.

Answer (score 5):

If default synced folder strategy (VirtualBox shared folders, I imagine) is slow for your use case, you can choose a different one and, if you need, maintain the two-way sync:

- If your host OS is **Linux** or **Mac OS X**, you can go with [NFS](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html).
- If your host OS is **Windows** you can instead choose [SMB](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html).

Rsync is very fast but, as you've pointed out, is one-way only.

Comment: You're right but speed is required in my case, NFS and SMB do not fit my needs...

Comment: @Emyl, do you have any experience using both NFS and SMB. How does SMB compare to NFS in terms of speed of sync.

Answer (score -1):

Vagrant mounts your project root as `/vargrant` folder inside box as 2 way share.

You can run your command there do get required files synced. Any I/O will be damn slow (like you already mentioned), however you will get your files. For other stuff use your 1-way synced folder.

Comment: My app doesn't reside in that folder otherwise as you mentioned it would be damn slow. And copying the files that have to be moved there would also requires too much work and make it slow...

Comment: Vagrant mounts that folder for it's own purposes. Even when you dont ask it to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but still this makes the process too slow or complicated (if I build another script that moves a the newly created files excluding cache/logs ...)

Comment: I personally disable sync (on Windows) and rely on IDE's auto-upload feature. Also I run commands ONLY inside the box. Some of those requires to manually download files from the box, however you can see logs from inside the box just fine.

Comment: I agree with you, every tasks has to be made within the bow otherwise you loose the advantage of centralizing boxes with Vagrant. Still in my case (Symfony framework) code is generated using specific commands, and those generated classes often requires you to work on them after being generated so you need those to be available in your IDE (local). See below for my way to handle this.